# c++ Огромный конструктор с параметрами

Tags: c++, конструктор, code-style, setter

Стоит ли делать конструктор класса (не важно, с параметрами или без) "всеобъемлющим"? Т.е. чтобы конструктор принимал значения для всех параметров класса, которые нужны для корректной его работы? Просто из-за этого он оказывается очень уж длинным. Или можно часть из них оставить на сеттеры, которые получается в обязательном порядке придется использовать после вызова конструктора? Как принято и лучше?

Comment: Ну, я бы сказал, что имеет смысл подумать над дизайном класса, если для его работы требуется такое огромное количество параметров. Это, пользуясь терминологией рефакторинга, тот самый "душок", который намекает, что пора задуматься о рефакторинге. Как личное мнение: если где-то приходится полагаться на человека ("сначала обязательно перекрой этот кран, а потом открой эти два, но только одновременно, а не по одному"), то это не самая надежная система...

Comment: Тут может напрашивается шаблон проектирования Строитель.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обязательных сеттеров быть не должно по многим причинам, но конкретно в вашем случае, по сути, вы делаете объявление еще больше громоздким и многострочным. Вместо условного:

```
// псевдокод
obj = new ObjClass(a, b, c, d, ...)
.. объект готов
```

вы получаете:

```
// псевдокод
obj = new ObjClass(a, b, ...)
obj->SetC(c)
obj->SetD(d, ...)
.. и только теперь объект готов
```

Очевидно, что второй вариант и длиннее, и более подвержен ошибкам (легко забыть какой-то из сеттеров, или перепутать порядок сеттеров).

---

Конструктор должен быть достаточным для создания адекватно-работающего экземпляра класса (обычно, пустой объект указанного класса, тоже считается валидным). Иногда, действительно, требуется много параметров (обычно, правда, это считается признаком неудачной архитектуры). Если для создания объекта нужно столько много параметров и они так же вместе используются где-то еще - имеет смысл объединить их, например, в структуру (или в отдельный класс/объект).

Comment: Просто в моем случае(небольшая самодельная библиотека) параметры для конструктора изначально не существуют, их должен вводить именно программист и в структуру засунуть их будет примерно тем же самым,что и писать их подряд в `new`

Comment: @SupremeMachine тут уж вам виднее, по конкретной ситуации )